# How to execute a GUI program at boot time?

Tags: gui

I am running stretch lite on Raspberry pi 1.
I have a Gambas program which generates a GUI screen. This should happen without manual intervention like keyboard or mouse

1.I require the program to execute automatically at boot time.

2.The resultant gui should be visible on the console.

Comment: Help clear some confusion for me: A "GUI screen" application running on a headless device without manual intervention strikes me as odd. In other words, GUIs exist to interact with users, so absent any user, I'm struggling to understand what you have in mind. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hello Goldilock,

Comment: Hello Goldilock, You are absolutely correct. When building the prototype, I am using it as a headless device. Ultimately it will boot on a 7 inch touchscreen display where the user will interact with my GUI  application. He will not see any booting or have any control over the Pi apart from the GUI.

Comment: OK, I think I understand that part of it now - thank you for the clarification. But when you say "ultimately it will boot...", does that mean you will still be running `stretch lite`, or will you switch to `stretch`?

Comment: What is the command from the command line to start the application? Does it run then without any problems? What user? Has it to run as root? Please address me with @Ingo.

Comment: Hello Goldilock,

Comment: Hello ingo, Thank you for your reply. I will be using stretch lite with lightdm package added to handle the GUI part. The command does not need root privileges. It runs from an executable file without any problem. The file name is test.gambas. I want to keep the distribution light. Rather than deleting packages from a heavy distribution , I am starting up with lean installation i.e. stretch ligh and will add on packages as and when they are required.